# HTTP headers: What is their location, Filename, Extension - how to edit HTTP headers?

Tags: http, http-headers, cpanel, hosted

**Every HTTP blog describes what HTTP headers are and what they do**... most of it repeatedly copied and pasted ad infinitum... however...

So far, I have failed to find any advice on how to locate these files.

Perhaps the 'hosted site' owner cannot access these files... if so it will save hours of research time if that can be confirmed.

This is what millions of website owners sees in CPanel:

```
/.lastlogin
/.gemrc
/.contactemail
/.md5sum
/.bash_profile
/.bash_logout
/.bashrc
/.zshrc
/.bash_profile.rpmnew
/public_html
/logs
/.cpanel
/tmp
/.mysql_backup
/.trash
/etc
/access-logs
/.cl.selector
/.cagefs
/.cphorde
/www
/public_ftp
/mail
/.htpasswds
```

**How do HTTP headers fit into this scheme of things?**

Comment: Headers are simply named values sent with an HTTP request/response, there is not much to them. What are you asking exactly? How to set custom response headers in Apache?

Comment: I want to know if I can edit them, or whether it is off limits to me... maybe the answer is that I can't and I must therefore use .htaccess... I've listed above, everything that I can see in CPanel... it's a goddady hosted site.